# Bootstrap Form Validation with jQuery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-validate

I've been trying to validate a Form with bootstrap and jQuery. I've looked at the other similar questions on here but none of the solutions were able to fix my problem.
My current code is

```
<form>
 <div class="form-group">
     <label class="control-label" for="email">Email:</label>
     <div class="input-group">
         <input class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your email address" name="emailAdd" type="text" />
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="password">Password:</label>
        <div class="input-group">
             <input class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your password" name="passWord" type="text" />
        </div>
   </div>
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

And my Script is this

```
$("form").validate({
rules: {
    emailAdd: {
        required: true
    },
    passWord: {
        required: true
    }
},
highlight: function(element) {
    $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
},
unhighlight: function(element) {
    $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
}
});
```

I'm really lost as to why this is not working and have tried so many different solutions I've seen online. If anybody would be able to point me in the right direction I'd appreciate it!

EDIT:

I reference jQuery and validate plug in like so:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.15.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Ideally, I want to be able to limit the logins and signups to certain email domains. So I thought this would be a good way to start. The email and password fields must be filled with some value before submit is pressed. If not, I want to highlight the box red and say 'Field is Required', or something similar. Currently when I press the submit button, the page just refreshes.

Sorry for not providing enough information in my original post!

Comment: Did you include validate plugin to your project?

Comment: Stupid question: are you referencing the plugin?  I tried using this with another project I was working on and found it a pain... so I wrote my own.

Comment: There's no validation messages?  The form does not submit?  The form submits with errors?  The Bootstrap style is missing?  **Please explain *"not working"***

Comment: See edit for more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this
in html

```
<form action="#" onsubmit="submitForm();return false">


<div class="form-group">
     <label class="control-label" for="email">Email:</label>
     <div class="input-group">
         <input class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your email address" name="emailAdd" type="text" id="email" required/>
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="password">Password:</label>
        <div class="input-group">
             <input class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your password" name="passWord" type="text" id="password" required/>
        </div>
   </div>
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

in jquery

```
function submitForm(){
var email = $('#email').val();
var password= $('#password').val();
}
```

Comment: I added the 'required' to my original code and that has worked for highlighting the input box when they are empty. Thanks very much, can't believe I missed something so simple. I have a short question for moving forward. I'd like to ensure that the email address has a certain domain in the string value. Can I check this using jQuery too?

Comment: @Kanery You can use to email field as <input type = "email"> and can also use jquery.remember use html 5 vaesion as put like this <!DOCTYPE html> top of the web page. Go ahed,good luck

Answer (score 2):

Hello you have one problem loading dependencies.
jquery.validate.js requires jquery.js you must load in order.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.15.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
```

And your are not using email validations, you need add the property email:true

```
emailAdd: {
        required: true,
        email: true
    },
```

See how it works on:

https://jsfiddle.net/gph2Lz2z/

Good day!

Comment: Hey man that's perfect! I didn't know about the 'email:true' operation. Is there any method I can use to allow only certain email domains?

Comment: It only work use validation checking email consistency, see [link](http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.methods/)